# How to catch and translate incoming audio stream in other languages for an iOS Client app using PJSIP?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, voip, pjsip

I want to integrate language converter in VoIP based iOS client app which will translate real time incoming audio stream to other selected languages based on user choice, I am using PjSip open source library to support VoIP Calls.

For language translation I want to use speech to text and text to speech open source library.

Now I am facing following issues :

1. How to catch the incoming audio stream in PJSip ?
2. How to send the converted audio stream which user can listen like in
   normal audio call ?

Please help.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found one possibility to catch the incoming audio stream could be to define REC_FILE in conference.c .

For example: #define  REC_FILE "/mypath/myname.pcm".

PJSIP will store the frames unformatted (plain PCM data) in the given file.