# PJSUA2 / PJSIP Python Real-Time Audio Streams

Tags: python, python-3.x, pjsip, pjsua2

currently im writing a script using PJSUA2 in Python3. The goal of the script is to make voice-calls using SIP. The script is working so far. With `createRecorder()` and `createPlayer()` and transmitting to them I'm able to record the calls and play some wav Files.

The problem is now I don't have any idea to access the audio data in real time. 
I want to pass the audio stream to an API and stream back the result.

After some research if found in the documentations something like this:
https://www.pjsip.org/pjmedia/docs/html/group__PJMED__STRM.htm#ga67575c8e7b15e325b98ebaa89639b550

But I don't have any idea to use this in Python

Comment: I'm also trying the same,building a simple sip client.I'm able to register with sample script provided by pjsip but failed to make calls! can u help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to catch and translate incoming audio stream in other languages for an iOS Client app using PJSIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31023274/how-to-catch-and-translate-incoming-audio-stream-in-other-languages-for-an-ios-c)